# Tags: [ionic] or [ionic-framework] -- 2 tags with same meaning

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

There are two tags being used to identify questions on the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/):

- [ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic) has 3,307 questions
- [ionic-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic-framework) has 4,567 questions.
- There are 1,288 questions with both tags.

> **Update:** These tags have grown quite substantially since I first made this post (numbers updated to reflect this. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Usually, in the case of synonyms like this, we use the [synonym system](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic-framework/synonyms). Unfortunately, in this case I don't think there are [enough top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic-framework/topusers) to make that happen soon.

Comment: I was on my way to ask for this synonym request, but I'm agreeing with you here.  This really *should* change, since it means that the questions about the framework are fragmented.