# User suggesting mass retags from one potential synonym to another

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-synonym-process

While reviewing suggested edits, I found a user whose [last five or so suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4694621/moonnoon?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) consisted of retagging [subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories) to [subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory) and small improvements to the title (usually removing a tag from the title).

There is a [long-abandoned synonym request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252105/4320665) for these tags that has never gone anywhere.  This user seems to be trying to suggest all the retags alone in an almost rogue burnination attempt.  And they are fairly borderline suggestions at that (I would personally reject most of them).    What's the proper protocol for this?

Comment: Comment on one of the users old questions letting them know that they should bring up synonym requests on meta.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've done that and also given them the link to this meta question.

Comment: Thank you for making this an issue - I found the old request before starting retagging but I thought it was dead, so I decided to change `subdirectories` to a more popular `subdirectories` little by little. I thought this is the way it should be done. ([the one-by-one approach was introduced to me at the very beginning of my presence here at SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290088/setting-a-proper-tag-for-the-shakespeare-programming-language-related-questions))

Comment: @moonnoon cool I'm going to delete the other meta comment on your question now that you've found this post.  Although, we might have to wait for more community input on the proper thing to do.

Comment: @moonnoon The biggest issue that I try to stress to new editors is to fix as much as possible. When suggesting edits, at least three people (up to five) have to spend a review vote (of which they have only twenty per day) on your suggested edit in order to either approve or reject your edit. The only exceptions are improving an edit, which will automatically approve it, and rejecting and editing, which will automatically reject it (but the reviewer then should fix everything in the post).  If it were me, I probably would have reject and edited them to improve everything else that could be...

Comment: improved, in order to send you that message. Then I would have let you know what I am now. Basically, I could care less (not speaking for everyone) if you do edit like that (even though it is much easier to suggest a synonym request and have a mod do it automatically) as long as you fix everything that should be fixed in the post.

Comment: @moonnoon The proper way to deal with a potential synonym is to go to the tag page and suggest a synonym. Editing moves the question to the front page, which is not really desirable for what's essentially a no-op (if you're only fixing that). The post you linked to is different because you appear to want to retag **some** questions with that tag - this is not the same as synonymization, which makes 2 tags be treated as identical for most intents and purposes. The only problem is that the requirements to suggest or vote for synonyms is totally impractical, so many requests never go anywhere.

Comment: Hi, ryanyuyu. I saw your comment on an old post of mine. You definitely have a valid point, I will take that in mind. I want to create a tag synonym, but you need 2.5k rep for that. I will see if I can request a synonym. Thanks.

Comment: @mhx yeah, there is [this forgotten request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285228/tags-ionic-or-ionic-framework-2-tags-with-same-meaning)...  Still waiting for an answer to this post.  Hopefully, someone will offer a better solution than "just wait."  At any rate, I'd personally stop looking for those kinds of retagging edits.  Some of your other edits are good though because they greatly improve the readability of posts.